# detect the "up" volume button on the device when is in the highest level

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

I'm trying to detect the "up volume" button on the device and run a method.

The next code works fine detecting the changes of the volume level, but when I'm on the highest level the selector isn't called (because the in the volume level doesn't occur any change)

```
 AVAudioSession* audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [audioSession setActive:YES error:nil];
    [audioSession addObserver:self
                   forKeyPath:@"outputVolume"
                      options:0
                      context:nil];
```

Is there any workaround that I can do to detect the "up volume" button when the device has de highest level of volume?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When the user changes the volume to the highest setting, instead of setting it to max, set it to MAX - some small amount. Then the callback will always be called because the volume can never be truly maxed out.

Comment: No, the observeValueForKeyPath is not called when  the volume reach the highest level and the button of volume up is pressed again

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't `outputVolume` itself have a value from 0.0 (min) to 1.0 (max)? Apple's  AVAudioSession Class Reference does say that your way is the way to monitor if changes are occurring, but couldn't you check the actual value of the `outputVolume` property for `audioSession` when you need to know if the volume is turned up to max?